# Conducting a proof-of-concept attack on an open MySQL port

Tags: penetration-test, mysql

I am not very experienced nor do I have acceptable knowledge, that is why I have signed up to work on a small project to gain some experience, where they don't seem to care about security much.

After running a scan, I noticed that they have many unnecessary open ports (including MySQL server: 3306) and are horrifically vulnerable.

I want to somehow show them that what they think is a passive thing is a great way of exploiting their system, but I am not looking to run a full penetration or Thread Emulation test, since I am not that experienced to go through these.

Is there any way to access their database without causing them harm, just to notify them about the situation?

Comment: What you want to do is a limited penetration test to show the risks. Do they have a need to expose that port to the internet? Is there a firewall in front?

Comment: @schroeder No they don't, they even have IMAP and SMTP open, why would a website need those without requiring email verification?

Comment: Then a brute-force login attempt might show the threats without damaging much. We can't say what some random site may or may not need.

Comment: By default, [connections on MySQL port 3306 are not encrypted](https://serverfault.com/questions/261134/).  If you are in a position where you can passively observe traffic on this port, you ought to be able to pickup authorization credentials, which you can then use to query the database yourself.  This ought to get their attention.

Comment: @mti2935 I would be glad if you could explain the methods a bit more in an answer, as I have mentioned, I am still unprofessional in this industry.

Comment: Basically, you can use a tool like [wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) to view the packets as the go across the network.  If the connections to MySQL on port 3306 are not encrypted (which, is the case by default), then you'll be able to see authorization credentials in the clear, as well as the queries themselves, and the responses.

Comment: Any attempt to "notify someone about a security problem you discovered" is a crime in most countries.

Answer (score 1):

An open MySQL port (or any other port) is not inherently an immediate security risk. Barring any outdated software or zero-day vulnerabilities in the service, real risks likely only exist if there were database accounts on this server with no password or guessable/weak credentials that are allowed to log in from the internet, which is an unlikely configuration if it is just used by the web server on the same host.

That said, there aren't many (any?) valid use cases for publicly-exposed MySQL IMO, and having it this way only adds unnecessary attack surface. As mentioned by @mti2935, if anyone connects to this service remotely, they are sending their credentials in the clear over the internet.